# How to define dependencies between bazaar repositories

Tags: bazaar

Before splitting up a large project stored in bzr into multiples repos, I'd like the ability to define dependencies between the multiple repos.

E.g., if I define repo A and B to depend on repo Common, then when branching repo A, repo Common should also be branched. Ditto for repo B.

Anyone know any way to achieve this ?

Many Thanks,
A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bzr-externals plugin](https://launchpad.net/bzr-externals) can more or less do this. I use it with its shortcomings, hopefully I'll see nested trees implemented in bzr core in my lifetime..